# the change of variables formula and applications of integration

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $w$ be the first octant of the ball $x^2+y^2+z^2≤a^2$, where $x\ge0,y\ge0,z\ge0$.Evaluate the improper integral
$$\iiint_w \frac{((x^2+y^2+z^2))^{1/4}}{\sqrt{z+((x^2+y^2+z^2))^2 }}dxdydz$$
by changing variables.

Comment: The integrand is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, you are integrating over the first octant.  Switch to sphericals and get a double integral:

$$\frac{\pi}{2} \int_0^a dr \: r^2 \int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta \frac{\sin{\theta}}{\sqrt{\cos{\theta} + r^3}}$$

Work right to left.  Both integrals are easily evaluated via substitution.  The result I get is

$$\frac{\pi}{9} [(a^3+1)^{3/2}-a^{9/2}-1]$$